# SSRS Display records for same desription in one row and different values on different columns

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Currently it displays as follows

[image]

I want the highlighted entries to populate an area shown by the arrow and not repeating description for different month, as shown

[image]

My current design view is as follows

[image]

After adding a child group or a group below branch, this is the result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPeQM.png)

Comment: You might be missing a row group on the ProductClass. You can add a child group below Branch, for the ProdcutClass and try again.

Comment: I tried to add a child group below Branch, but the result is a consecutive list of similar description like for Jan on top followed by the following month etc, but my desire is to have them listed side by side with single row description @Rigerta Demiri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can;t see what your grouping is like but I'm guessing the Branch Row group is just grouped on branch. If that's the case then everything else is in the details group. As this has not grouping, anything outside of the branch group will be shown as a detail no (no grouping).

I think all you need to do is set the grouping on the details group to group by ProductClass (and optionally rename the group so it makes sense) then change the cell containing `[NonFuelItem]` to be `SUM([NonFuelItem])`.

Comment: I tried to add a group below Branch by ProductClass as well as [SUM(NonFuelItem)], but the result is a consecutive list of similar description like for Jan on top followed by the following month etc, but my desire is to have them listed side by side with single row description @Alan Schofield

Comment: Can you edit your post and describe what grouping is on each group. You only need two groups. One by Branch and one by ProductClass. There is no need for a details group, that's why I suggested just adding a group to your details group and changing the the data cell to a sum.

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked. I removed the details group and left with the two groups as you indicated. @Alan Schofield